# Getting all information about ways from python overpass library?

Tags: python, overpass-api

I'm having problems getting started with the overpass QL python library. I want to get a collection of ways that match the search criteria, but I can't seem to get anything but the points. I need to know which points belong with which ways so that I can draw them properly.

```
$ ipython
In [1]: import overpass
In [2]: api = overpass.API()
In [3]: ways_featureset = api.get('way(42.819,-73.881,42.820,-73.880);>;')
In [4]: ways_featureset['features'][0]
Out[4]: {"geometry": {"coordinates": [-73.8925346, 42.8155621], "type": "Point"}, "id": 42001122, "properties": {"highway": "traffic_signals"}, "type": "Feature"}
In [5]: non_points = [way for way in ways_featureset['features'] if way['geometry']['type'] != 'Point']
In [6]: non_points
Out[6]: []
```

I think that I need to do something similar to the "out skel" call, but you aren't able to do that in the library according to the docs (because the library handles appending `out` for you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `verbosity` of the `get()` output.

Try this:

```
>>> import overpass
>>> api = overpass.API()
>>> data = api.get('way(42.819,-73.881,42.820,-73.880);(._;>;)', verbosity='geom')
>>> [f for f in data.features  if f.geometry['type'] == "LineString"]
```